# How should I correct this NMOS static inverter?

Tags: circuit-design, inverter, nmos

So in my notebook I have this circuit scheme for a NMOS static inverter:

[image]

Vi is the input
Vo is the output
VDD is the voltage source
It is obvious that the M2 MOSFET will never turn on. Is the circuit wrong? Is something missing?
Please help me find a way to correct this STATIC NMOS Inverter.

Comment: Your circuit shows enhancement mode MOSFETs hence, your circuit will never work. If the upper MOSFET was a depletion mode MOSFET, it stands a chance. Maybe you didn't transcribe it from your book correctly?

Comment: M2 should act as the so-called "dynamic load" (constant current source).

Comment: @Andyaka indeed the M2 transistor is a depletion mode MOSFET.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I have understood that it needs to function as a dynamic load, but why was it designed this way (a not working way) in the notebook?

Comment: @Kudor you've drawn it as an enhancement mode MOSFET.

Comment: @Kudor, As far as I know such "constant current diodes" are made with some kind of JFET that produce a certain current at zero GS voltage (short connection).

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely an internal schematic of an integrated circuit and as such it contains devices and connections which are not available as discrete solutions. 
In this case, the M2 is also an N-channel MOSFET, but the substrate, which usually has its other end connected to the Source electrode, is not connected to Source but rather free-floating and connected to ground or zero point of the circuit, most likely to act as a constant current source.